# How to set visibility for textblocks in QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, pyqt

i tried to hide textblock's in QTextEdit, but it doesn't work:

```
block = textedit.document().begin()
block.setVisible(False)
```

This code works fine for QPlainTextEdit, but not for QTextEdit. In documentation i haven't found any mention of how it should work for QTextEdit, just following:

> void QTextBlock::setVisible ( bool visible ) 
>   Sets the block's visibility
>   to visible.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt
>   4.4.
>
> See also isVisible().

How can i hide block's in QTextEdit?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed the behavior your describe. In addition, I've confirmed that, in the code you've given, following the setVisible method the block's visibility is indeed False.

So, the clearest explanation I see is this: QPlainTextEdit does not inherit from QTextEdit. They both inherit from QScrollableArea and I can only assume that QTextEdit does not respect the visibility of its document's blocks. The documents used by QPlainTextEdit use QPlainTextLayout objects, and QTextEdit has something else that I cannot determine.

So... I'm not sure it can be done in the way you are intending. One alternative is to filter the text *before* it gets into the QTextEdit, and Python is well-suited for that task.

```
self.paragraphs = ["First paragraph","Second Paragraph","Third Paragraph",]
self.display_text = '\n'.join(self.paragraphs[1:])
self.textedit.setText(self.display_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, nine years on, this now seems to be working (Qt 5.13.1). Following the example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527544/1447002), but with C++:

```
QTextCursor cursor(&mDocument);
cursor.insertText("Hello world! ");
cursor.insertBlock();
cursor.insertText("Goodbye world! ");
cursor.block().setVisible(false);
```

When I display the document I see:

```
Hello world!
```