# Hiding text with QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: qt, pyqt, syntax-highlighting, qtextdocument, qplaintextedit

**Problem:** I want to implement a text editing widget for text with additional tags.
I'd like some tags to be invisible in some cases so that they do not distract the user.

**Environment:** I'm using `PyQt` and prefer to use `QPlainTextWidget` and `QSyntaxHighlighter`.

**Approach:** With `QSyntaxHighlighter` I can set `QTextCharFormat` for the strings which match my requirement. `QTextCharFormat` has gives me all font properties like size, colors, etc. ***but:*** I haven't found a option to hide the text or reduce its size to zero.

I don't want to remove or replace the tags, as this will introduce a lot more code (copying should contain tags and without I can't use `QSyntaxHighlighter` for formating the remaining text according to the tags).

**Update:** So far I found a ugly hack. By setting the *QTextFormat::FontLetterSpacing* to a small value, the text will consume less and less space. In combination with a transparent color the text is something like invisible.

**Problem:** In my test this worked only for letter spacings down to 0.016 %. Below the spacing is reseted to 100 %.

Comment: Well, plain text is plain text. Try to use the non-plain widget.

Comment: I haven't found corresponding options in `QTextEdit`. AFAIK the difference is limited to the scrolling behavior, tables, frames and things like images. The functions which might enable to hide text are the same as for the `QPlainTextEdit`. Other then that there are mo more advanced classes inside Qt. QScintilla would mean using something completely different.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the underlying `QTextDocument` for this. It consists of blocks whose visibility can be turned on and off using `setVisible`. Use a `QTextCursor` to insert the text and new blocks and switch visibility. As a bonus the copy function copies the content of non-visible blocks anyway.

Notes: See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html) of `QTextCursor` for more information. In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698129/how-to-set-visibility-for-textblocks-in-qtextedit) here is was reported that setting the visibility is not working on `QTextEdits`.

Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

w = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
w.show()

t = QtGui.QTextCursor(w.document())
t.insertText('plain text')
t.insertBlock()
t.insertText('tags, tags, tags')
t.block().setVisible(False)

print(w.document().toPlainText())

app.exec_()
```